# Figure out which .conf file apache2 is using

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf

I am running a website at http://203.101.226.32:7000/

where it shows some error. This was done by another colleague but I couldn't figure out where did he configure apache2 to run this app. Is there any way that I can trace it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file should be here.

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/your_config_file`

You can edit that file by using nano or your favorite editor.

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/your_config_file`

Comment: no it isn't there. And I dig into apache2.conf and there is no such settings too.

Comment: my folder only has 1 conf pointing to port 80, but I don't know how on earth it managed to point to port 7000.

Comment: @cherhan please post that 1 conf file and it should be `proxypass` to `7000` port.

Comment: @cherhan if it resolve your issue, please give an upvote and accept as answer.

Comment: please post that configuration file